# GWT TabLayoutPanel not allow text selection on tabs

Tags: css, gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

Hi is there a way to not allow text selection on tabs for GWT TabLayoutPanel (and other gwt widgets)?

I tried to use css like:

```
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel {
    user-select: none;
}

.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs {
    user-select: none;
}
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelContent {
    user-select: none;
} 

.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab {
    user-select: none;
} 

.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab-selected {
    user-select: none;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try it on gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner with this values:
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */

  /* No support for these yet, use at own risk */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

Comment: yes this was it! thanks, i figured from Tobika´s answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been answered: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

for IE < 10 and opera:

```
<div id="foo" unselectable="on">...</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this answered me, i was only putting user-select: none;

Comment: i had seen the other parts like -webkit-touch-callout: none;   but i didn´t realize they were also required. Thanks!